# How can I make a VSCode theme recognize C# interfaces?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get a theme for Visual Studio Code working to what I want. Currently, I'm trying to use Obsidian working with C# rules, but I'm not sure which key word to use to override color customizations. VSCode does not seem to recognize interfaces as they're language specific.

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "functions" :{
            "foreground": "#F1F2F3"
        },
        "interface": { //not valid
            "foreground": "#B48C8C"
        } 
    }
```

How can I get VSCode color customizations to recognize c# specific syntaxes?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*editor.tokenColorCustomizations* can use a number of values: *comments, functions, keywords, numbers, strings, types and variables*.  If none of those work for you **textMateRules** is available as well.  So you can do something like:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [{
        "scope": "yourScopeHere",
        "settings": {
            "fontStyle": "italic",
            "foreground": "#C69650"
        }
    }]
   },
```

So you just have to figure out what scope you need for "*interface*".

For that, try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> and type scope: choose

```
Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes
```

and for whichever keyword is selected, like *interface* you will get a listing of its textmate scope.  That should be inserted as the scope value above. [In my experience, it is more accurate to open the "*Inspect TM Scopes*" panel and then click a couple of items and then the one, like *interface*, that you want - the scope panel will remain open.]  You can copy from the scopes panel.

You may need only the main scope listed, but if need to narrow its scope you can include the others listed in a comma-separated list in the *scopes: ..., ..., ...*

Comment: So this sort of worked. If I define an interface, the token is identified as `entity.name.type.interface.cs` but If I go to a property of another class and look at it's variable type it only shows the token for `storage.type.cs` same as every other variable type. Same thing if I implement an interface, it's only known as storage.type.cs. However, you put me on the right path and I'm doing a bit more customization with themes via the actual json files.

Comment: @PremierBromanov were you able to find what you wanted? I'm looking for same without luck!

Comment: @FernandoMoreira nope! just got used to it, sadly

Comment: For those who just want to copy-paste de configuration:

    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [{
            "scope": "storage.type.cs,entity.name.type.interface.cs",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#C69650"
            }
        }]
    }

Comment: Is there a way to check the current defaults for default scopes?

Comment: In version VSCode 1.67 April 2022, the inspector is called `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Davi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56612344/8818430):

1. Edit "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\csharp\syntaxes\csharp.tmLanguage.json":
2. Find:

   {"name":"storage.type.cs","match":"@?[*[:alpha:]][*[:alnum:]]*"}
3. Replace with:

   {"name":"storage.type.interface.cs","match":"@?[I][[:upper:]][*[:alpha:]][*[:alnum:]]*"},{"name":"storage.type.cs","match":"@?[_[:alpha:]][_[:alnum:]]*"}
4. Add to settings.json:

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Default Dark+]": { // remove scope to apply to all themes
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": "entity.name.type.interface.cs",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#b8d7a3"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "scope": "storage.type.interface.cs",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#b8d7a3"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

VSCode 1.63.2:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> > Open Settings (JSON)

Paste this:

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
            "[Default Dark+]": { 
                "textMateRules": [
                    {
                        "scope": "entity.name.type.interface",
                        "settings": {
                            "foreground": "#a4ddaf"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

Comment: It's better this to be a comment, but I have reputation for create answer only....

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can be partially done by editing "Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\csharp\syntaxes" by adding support for "storage.type.interface.cs" with a regular expression that matches the convention.

Something like `[I]([A-Z][a-z][A-Za-z]*)`

You could also exclude possible mismatches like
`IISManager, IPhoneDevice`

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide
https://www.apeth.com/nonblog/stories/textmatebundle.html

good luck with that and please let me know if you got it done