# Make VSCode Variables have Colour

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I would like to make variables displayed with colours.

This is how it looks:

[image: Python]

This is how I want it to be:

[image: Variable Colored]

Looking through [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes), I cannot find any settings that allow me to change this.

Answer (score 17):

Try this setting in your settings.json:

```
 "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "variables": "#f00"
 },
```

There are a few such *simple* token color customizations available: variables, comments, keywords, functions, numbers, strings and types.  Those only allow setting the *color* though.

If you use  "textMateRules" you can set more properties.  For example:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "scope": "comment",
      "settings": {
        "fontStyle": "italic",
        "foreground": "#C69650"
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works for some things, but not everything.
For instance, [this](https://i.imgur.com/xmw07V2.png), shows the variable `self` turned red, but the `search_obj` is not, nor is the `get_key` part, which is supposed to have function applied to it - the function does apply to the definition only.

Comment: You can also try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272835/how-can-i-make-a-vscode-theme-recognize-c-sharp-interfaces/47274837#47274837 more detailed scopes might help you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 10):

This is working for me. It makes it look like the default Javascript formatting as far as I can see.

In `settings.json`

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "meta.function-call.generic.python",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#DCDCAA"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "source.python",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#9CDCFE"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "punctuation.definition.string.begin",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#ce9178"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "punctuation.definition.string.end",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#ce9178"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "punctuation",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#dfdfdf"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the color in `tokenColors` to customize the colors (basic example):

***SomeTheme.json***

```
{ 
 "name": "Some Theme",
 "type": "dark",
 "colors": {
 ...
},
"tokenColors": [
   {
    "name": "Variables",
    "scope": "variable",
    "settings": {
    "foreground": "#e06c75"
   }
  },
 ]
}
```

I don't have `VSCode`, although from looking at [another themes JSON](https://github.com/Binaryify/OneDark-Pro/blob/master/themes/OneDark-Pro.json) it looks similar.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
{
            "scope": [
             "variable.other.readwrite", 
             ],
             "settings": {
             "foreground": "#ffffff",
             }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

strange that the answer is not so obvious
for everybody searching:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MatthewNespor.vscode-color-identifiers-mode