# Text Colors in VSC Editor and Terminal - Atom One Theme

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code

Why does VSC (Intellisense?) not recognize certain functions/variables in the Python environment? (see the underlined text in the attached photo). It's working fine for C (using C/C++ extension), otherwise. I am using the Atom One theme and for the C environment every word/command seems to have some color. I tried reinstalling the extensions and going through the settings the best I could, but I can't figure it out.

As a side question, why do I get colored paths in Terminal on my Windows machine (see bottom part of the attached picture), but not on my Mac? Is there some default setting for this that's activated only on Windows? I am a fan of it and I'd like to get my Mac showing some colors too.

[image]

Mac:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the terminal text colors, I found the solution here: [Color theme for VS Code integrated terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307949/color-theme-for-vs-code-integrated-terminal).
And here, for more detailed info: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

As far as variable colors changes for Python, this was useful: [Make VSCode Variables have Colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724696/make-vscode-variables-have-colour)