# Defined variable is visible in white color in visual studio code for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am learning python and I am using visual studio code for it.

I have an office laptop and a personal laptop. When I define any variable in my office laptop the color of the variable is White.

But when I open the same python file the color of the variable is colored (blue color).

I have selected the same theme in both laptops and extensions are also the same. I don't know which setting should I change so the variable name will be colored.

Here is the screenshot of my code and extension installed. You can see that number_a, number_b and sum_a_b are visible in white color.

Can anyone please help me to fix this? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Do you want a separate theme for your vscode, if so " CTRL.K + CTRL.T ". @Gulammustufa Momin

Comment: No. declared variable should be colored instead of white color.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724696/make-vscode-variables-have-colour. This might help.

Answer (score 0):

Despite customizing syntax highlighting in `Settings.json` as @help said, Python extension itself has this feature that highlight variables.

You may **reset** VS Code to solve the variables wasn't highlighted correctly in your laptop. Delete the data folders and reinstall Python extension, the question should be fixed:

> **Windows** - Delete `%APPDATA%\Code` and `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode`.
> **macOS** - Delete `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code` and `~/.vscode`.
> **Linux** - Delete `$HOME/.config/Code` and `~/.vscode`.

Comment: Yes it worked after manually added code in Setting.json file.

Comment: @GulammustufaMomin. Glad to know your question has been solved. For your reference, reset helps when encountering some other questions :)