# Changing the style of pipe | character in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

My current theme italicizes keywords, comments, and unfortunately, the pipe (|) symbol as well. Pipes should be absolutely vertical.

I found that it is possible to change the theme and below is the example for that:

```
editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "name": "Tag brackets",
      "scope": ["punctuation.definition.tag"],
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#BBBBBB"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

which changes the color of angle brackets. So I'm thinking there's a similar **"scope"** key for the pipe characters as well?

Any help is appreciated !!!

Comment: use the Dev tool to find the textmate scope (search ctrl+p for `scope`) of this pipe symbol

Comment: @rioV8 I found that it's a span with class = "mtk9 mtki", Is that the scope then?

Comment: use `Ctrl+Shift+P` and search `scope`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47274837/836330 for example.